# Importing Python script with nonstandard name

Tags: python, import, module

I am writing a series of python scripts to extend the QGIS software suite.  As such I am trying to follow their naming conventions.  In this instance the file I am trying to import is called "r.sun.distributed".  Ive tried using import r.sun.distributed and **import**("r.sun.distributed") However, python says it can't find a module by that name in both cases.

Is there a work around, or do I need to rename my scripts so they fit Python's conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module to import modules without `.py` extension:

```
import imp
imp.load_source(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert it to .pyc to call it.

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('filename.py')
```